# In node.js express , the default router always jump to index.html static file

Tags: node.js, express, default, router

My default router is :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("default");
    res.send("ok");
});
```

If I don't have a `index.html` in my static directory, the `log` and `send` will output as will,

but when I add `index.html`, the router will direct jump to the page, then I change the name `index` to another name, it doesn't jump again.

Why this happen? How can I change this setting things?

Comment: Can you give a bit more code about how you have set up your middleware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your middleware order and configuration that causes this behavior. You presumably are using the `static` middleware and by default that happens before the `app.router` middleware. The solution is either:

- configure your static middleware to only serve exact file matches without any automatic `index.html` behavior
- put `app.user(app.router);` before your static middleware

Comment: Looks like `app.router` is depreciated https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x